# Multiline grep or sed

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I have a very large text file with multiple sections.  These sections include section headers.  I would like to extract the section headers and print them with grep or sed.  The file looks like this:

```
=========
Section Header
=========
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant. A iaculis at erat pellentesque. Libero justo laoreet sit amet cursus. Blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in dictum non. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at. Elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus. Et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris. Rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi. Urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu. Imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta. Vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan. Diam ut venenatis tellus in. Ultrices dui sapien eget mi. Vivamus arcu felis bibendum ut. Nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis.

==========
Another Section
==========
Dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper. Adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et. Malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis natoque. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu. Eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna sit amet purus. Arcu non odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed. Cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada. Dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc. Magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices. Nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras.
```

The amount of equal signs in the header can vary.  I would like to print each section header on a separate line.  Preferably with look behind to remove the equal sign lines.

Comment: Are multi-line headers possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try also

```
$ sed -n '/=\+/ {n;p;n;}' file
Section Header
Another Section
```

On a line of one or more `=`, get next line, print it, and get next line (to be forgotten).

Comment: Perfect!  Short and sweet and only uses one single command.  Thanks!  Now I need to research WHY it worked.  The n;p;n part is something that I don't know about, and I don't like to just copy and paste.  :)

Comment: So I got to thinking about it.  The n;p;n part is just an array of pattern flags, right?  If so, what is the 'n' pattern flag?  I know 'p' is print.  Definitely a new way (to me) of using pattern flags!

Comment: No, both "n" and "p" are sed commands / functions. "n" reads next line into pattern space, "p" prints it (c.f. man sed). "p" can be misleading as it is a flag to the "s" command as well.

Comment: Ah.  I see the section in the man file.  Definitely gives me something new to study.  I've only ever used the 's' command in sed.  Masterful.  Thanks again!

Comment: Note that `\+` requires GNU `sed` and that the expression that you use would match a line saying e.g. `foo=bar`.

Comment: That would fail if any other line in the file contained a `=` symbol, you need the regexp to be `^=\+$` or, more robustly and portably,`^=========+$` or `^=\{9,\}$`.

Comment: This won't work if there are blank lines betwee  `=` and the header

Answer (score 2):

Robustly using any awk in any shell on every Unix box whether your headers are single or multi-line:

```
$ awk '/^=+$/{f=!f; next} f' file
Section Header
Another Section
```

Use a regexp like `^={9,}$` if you have other lines that contain all equals signs but don't indicate header parts.

Answer (score 1):

Commands in `sed` may be addressed by line numbers, regular expressions, or by ranges possibly consisting of combinations of the two.

The range `/^==*$/,/^==*$/` matches the header lines that are surrounded by your `====` markers. The regular expression `^==*$` may be read as "a line containing one or more `=` character, but nothing else". This means that the following would print all the headers, including the header marker lines:

```bsh
sed -n '/^==*$/,/^==*$/ p' file
```

To avoid printing the header marker lines, only call `p` for lines that is not one of the header markers:

```bsh
sed -n '/^==*$/,/^==*$/ { // !p; }' file
```

An empty regular expression reuses the most recently used regular expression, and the `!` makes sure to call `p` when the expression does *not* match.

Given the text in your question, this results in

```
Section Header
Another Section
```

This would work also for multi-line headers:

```bsh
$ cat file
====
Title: Hello world
Author: Me
====

Text goes here

====
That was it
The end
====
```

```bsh
$ sed -n '/^==*$/,/^==*$/ { // !p; }' file
Title: Hello world
Author: Me
That was it
The end
```