# Using GNU sed to extract header names between two pattern lines possibly separated by blank lines

Tags: linux, sed, gnu

I have the following file:

```
------

Introduction
----------
Optio eum enim ut. Et quia molestias eos. Doloribus laborum quia quae. Magnam cupiditate quis consectetur.

-----
Chapter1: Foo
-----

Odit beatae eius voluptas temporibus sint quia. Eos et tempora similique laboriosam optio consequatur quibusdam. Fugit suscipit cupiditate ea perspiciatis rem labore cum eos.

-----
Chapter bar


-----
Et consequatur quia quia et architecto et sunt. Perferendis qui deserunt qui est illo est sapiente ipsam. Fugiat vel amet magni in quam. Eligendi totam cum sapiente harum blanditiis minima
```

With the following constaints:

- The header symbol `-` appears at least 5 characters or more.
- There could be an arbitrary (but finite) number of blank lines between `-` and the header.

The expected output is:

```
Introduction
Chapter1: Foo
Chapter bar
```

I know this could be accomplished using `awk` but please don't suggest that. I would like to see a pure GNU sed solution.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
sed -n ':a; /-\+/{n; /^$/!{p; b a}}' input.txt
```

But that command doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiline grep or sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/682953/multiline-grep-or-sed)

Comment: @they: No that doesn't answer my question because it's doesn't account for blank lines between "=" and the header.

Comment: Just pipe through `sed '/^$/d'` or `awk 'length != 0'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This prints the lines that contain at least one alphabetical or numerical character, as long as they are inside a header.

```
sed -n '/^-----/,/^-----/{/[[:alnum:]]/p;}' file
```

- [GNU Sed manual: Range addresses](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Range-Addresses.html)

Answer (score 4):

I propose this solution:

```bsh
$ sed -n '/\-\{5,\}/,/\-\{5,\}/p' file | sed '/\-\+\|^$/d'
Introduction
Chapter1: Foo
Chapter bar
```

---

- `'/\-\{5,\}/,/\-\{5,\}/p'` select the sections between `-` (at least 5).
- `'/\-\+\|^$/d'` delete either blank lines or those starting with `-`.

Comment: That's too expensive. one `sed` process should be enough.

Comment: @OK-Validation Indeed, Quasímodos' answer, using ranges too, does that. The caveat, being too picky, is that  if there are lines between the range that don't have alnum characters, it won't print them. But it seems highly unlikely given your sample.

Answer (score 4):

While you can indeed do this in `sed`, other tools <del>would make it easier (IMO)</del><sup>1</sup> can also work. For example, in `awk`:

```
$ awk '/-----/ && !a{a=1;next} /-----/ && a{a=0}a' file 

Introduction
Chapter1: Foo
Chapter bar
```

And to get rid of the empty lines, you could do:

```
$ grep . file | awk '/-----/ && !a{a=1;next} /-----/ && a{a=0}a'
Introduction
Chapter1: Foo
Chapter bar
```

Or:

```
$ awk '!/./{next};/-----/ && !a{a=1;next} /-----/ && a{a=0}a' file 
Introduction
Chapter1: Foo
Chapter bar
```

The idea here is to set the variable `a` to `1` if it is currently 0 or unset (`!a`) and if the current line matches at least 5 `-`. We set it back to `0` if we find another line with 5 `-` when `a` is set to 1. We then print all lines where `a` is set (that's what the final `a` does: it will print if `a` evaluates to non-0).

Here's the same thing written in an easier to understand way:

```
awk '{ 
        if(!/./){ next } 
        if(/-----/ && !a){ a=1; next} 
        if(/-----/ && a){ a=0 } 
        if(a){ print }
    }' file
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>[Quasimodo's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/683199/22222) is even simpler!</sub>

Comment: Nice answer! I agree that awk works but it takes a lot of typing compared to sed simple syntax.

Comment: @OK-Validation heh, OK. I find this is shorter and more elegant than sed whose syntax I find particularly obscure. But that's why we have many options, everyone can choose the one they prefer! Please remember to [accept](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) whichever answer you prefer, there are some really good sed ones here!

Comment: Whoops, sorry @OK-Validation, I see you have already been told about accepting. Since you're aware of the mechanics, feel free to wait as long as you want, I didn't mean to pressure you to accept.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
sed -n '/^-\+$/,/^-\+$/{/^-*$/!p}' input.txt
```

---

Alternatively, you could also use `sed -z`:

```
sed -Ez 's/[^-]*-+[\n]*([^\n]*\n)[\n]*-+[^-]*/\1/g' input.txt
```

without `-E`:

```
sed -z 's/[^-]*-\+[\n]*\([^\n]*\n\)[\n]*-\+[^-]*/\1/g' input.txt
```

Note: While this works well for your example, it might have issues if `-` appears somewhere in the text. But I think, you could elaborate on that.

Comment: Indeed, with a line starting with `-` the command fails.

Comment: Not sure, why you mean it won't work, because for your example it does. But if you're happy with your version, I'm happy too ;-)